# group by platform, and display the arithmetic mean of sales

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Can't deal with sql query.

1. There is a table of platforms.
2. I have a sales table.
3. There is a table of connection between platforms and games.

**Table with games is the main.**

**Table chart**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxQDP.png)

Made sql query.

```
SELECT`Sales`.'Global_Sales',  Platform.name
FROM `Games_In_Platform` INNER JOIN `Sales` ON `Games_In_Platform`.`game_id`=`Sales`.`game_id`
JOIN Platform on Games_In_Platform.platform_id = Platform.id;
```

Got two columns

Platforms and global sales
photo of the received table (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEEhA.png)

How to group global sales by platform?
Output the arithmetic mean of global sales for each platform?
And do it in one request!

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `AVG` (*average*) aggregate function and put column that isn't aggregated (the *name*) into the `group by` clause.

```
SELECT avg(`Sales`.'Global_Sales') as average_sales,            --> this
       Platform.name
FROM `Games_In_Platform` INNER JOIN `Sales` ON `Games_In_Platform`.`game_id`=`Sales`.`game_id`
JOIN Platform on Games_In_Platform.platform_id = Platform.id
group by Platform.name                                          --> and this
```

---

As you commented that average isn't calculated correctly: it is not about the function, it works OK. For example:

```
SQL> select name, sales from test order by name;

NAME        SALES
------ ----------
name A        100      --> average for "name A" = (100 + 200) / 2  
name A        200      -->                      = 300 / 2 = 150
name B         50      --> average for "name B" =  50 / 1 = 50
```

So, what does the function return? It returns what we expect:

```
SQL> select name,
  2         avg(sales) average_sales
  3  from test
  4  group by name;

NAME   AVERAGE_SALES
------ -------------
name A           150
name B            50

SQL>
```

Therefore, if query returns unexpected result, do provide some sample data so that we'd see what's going on.

Comment: Wrong calculations

platform 2600 gives an average of 0.7
And should
5.54

Comment: I don't know what "platform 2600" is and why result should be 5.54 - you never provided any sample data. If you take a look at edited answer which now contains an example that shows what the AVG function returns, you'll see that it isn't about it (the function) but *something else*. What? No idea, until you provide test case (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data) which will let us see what's going on.

Comment: Everything is correct, thank you